# How to skip preceding maven goals in gitlab-ci build?

Tags: java, docker, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a java webservice and want to set separate test/build/deploy stages in `gitlab-ci`.
A flow would probably be simple as follows:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

test:
  stage: clean test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package -DskipTests=true

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package -DskipTests=true
```

Problem: each maven goal will execute the preceding lifecycle goals. Eg a `package` or `deploy` goal will by default also execute the `test` goal. Thus having to exclude it explicit with `skipTests=true`.

Anyways goals like `package` will still be re-executed on test + deploy.

Question: can this be further optimized? I mean, I would not want to rebuild the jar on each stage. Could I tell maven to reuse the jar, and skip any preceding goals?

I know that a single `deploy` stage would be sufficient for maven to execute the package and test goal under the hood. But then in my gitlab I'd always have failures in the `deploy` stage, while eg just a junit test in the `test` goal failed underneath.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. Maven is not constructed to support that.

You can use `skip` parameters of the those plugins which have them.

Alternatively, just use two steps with `mvn clean test` and then `mvn deploy -DskipTests=true`, which should not really take longer than a single `mvn clean deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [job artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) to access the results of previous stages (the compiled classes in this case). Also it would be reasonable to cache the local repository so that dependencies are downloaded only once. Example:

```yaml
default:
  image: maven:3

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

test-compile:
  stage: build
  script: mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test-compile
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/

test:
  stage: test
  script: mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
  # maven-compiler-plugin outputs "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date"
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package -DskipTests
```

It's also possible to have unit and integration tests run in parallel this way:

[image: a GitLab CI pipeline running unit and integration tests in parallel]